# Why is the behavior of `jest.useFakeTimers` different when called inside vs. outside of `beforeEach` in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, usefaketimers

## Overview

I encountered different behaviors of `jest.useFakeTimers` when it is called inside `beforeEach` versus called outside.

## Reproducible Examples

```js
// Foo.tsx

import * as React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

const Foo: React.FC = () => {
  const [timePassed, setTimePassed] = React.useState<number>(0);
  const [flag, setFlag] = React.useState(true);

  console.log(`timePassed: ${timePassed}, flag: ${flag}`);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (flag) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (timePassed > 1) {
          setFlag(false);
        }
        setTimePassed(timePassed + 1);
      }, 1);
    }
  }, [flag, timePassed]);

  return <View />;
};

export default Foo;
```

```js
// foo.outside.test.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import Foo from '../Foo';

jest.useFakeTimers();

describe('Test Foo', () => {
  test('1', () => {
    render(<Foo />);
    jest.runAllTimers();
  });

  test('2', () => {
    render(<Foo />);
    jest.runAllTimers();
  });
});
```

```js
// foo.inside.test.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import Foo from '../Foo';

describe('Test Foo', () => {
  // fake timer usage follows: https://testing-library.com/docs/using-fake-timers/
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });

  test('1', () => {
    render(<Foo />);
    jest.runAllTimers();
  });

  test('2', () => {
    render(<Foo />);
    jest.runAllTimers();
  });
});
```

## Test Results

### outside

```bash
$ npx jest __tests__/foo.outside.test.tsx
  console.log
    timePassed: 0, flag: true

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 1, flag: true

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 2, flag: true

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 2, flag: false

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 3, flag: false

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 0, flag: true

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 1, flag: true

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 2, flag: true

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 2, flag: false

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 3, flag: false

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

 PASS  __tests__/foo.outside.test.tsx
  Test Foo
    ✓ 1 (58 ms)
    ✓ 2 (21 ms)
```

### inside

```bash
$ npx jest __tests__/foo.inside.test.tsx                      1 ↵
  console.log
    timePassed: 0, flag: true

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 1, flag: true

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 2, flag: true

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 2, flag: false

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 3, flag: false

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 0, flag: true

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

  console.log
    timePassed: 1, flag: true

      at log (Foo.tsx:8:11)

 PASS  __tests__/foo.inside.test.tsx
  Test Foo
    ✓ 1 (62 ms)
    ✓ 2 (14 ms)
```

## Observations

It seems that in the **outside** setup, `jest.runAllTimers` runs the timer to the end in both test cases. However, in the **inside** setup, only the timer in the first test case runs to the end; the timer in the second test case exists prematurely.

## Question

Why is the behavior of the fake timer different when `jest.useFakeTimers` is called inside versus outside `beforeEach`? I expect both setup to run the timer to the end. Thus, the current behavior of the **inside** setup is a negative surprise.

## Machine and Software Info

- macOS Big Sur v11.6.5
- react: 17.0.2
- react-native: 0.65.1
- jest: 28.1.2
- @testing-library/react-native: 10.1.1
- typescript: 4.5.2